# Is it true that modern statistics was created to prove eugenics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

Karl Pearson, Francis Galton, R.a Fisher were all prominent figures in the development of modern statistics and were all proponents of Eugenics. Is this true that it was a scientific/mathematical field created to prove Eugenics?

Comment: 1. Faulty generalization. 2. Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: Fermat, Newton and Leibniz were all prominent figures in the development of calculus and were all proponents of Christianity. Therefore, calculus was created to prove Christianity. I suggest rephrasing the question into something less nonsensical and reasking on hsm SE.

Comment: so why were many of the giants of statistics into eugenics.?

Comment: @user4281: You should ask this question on [CrossValidated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  It is a question about the history of statistics; it is not a philosophy question.

Comment: @Ben: This probably wouldn't be answered on CrossValidated either.  Unfortunately this really belongs on a history of science SE!

Comment: @user4281 I don't think historians of statistics would say that the field was "created to prove" eugenics.  It's more like statistics and eugenics — along with genetics and psychometry — were deeply entangled for several decades, so that understanding the development of the one requires understanding the development of the others.  Check out Kevles' *In the Name of Eugenics*:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iL3yVS76YGmYb9QhEQH9aQsddK4VV0kq

Answer (score 1):

Statistics has a history spanning two and a half thousand years as part of risk analysis, a search for certainty in an uncertain world. I recommend Peter Bernstein, *Against the gods: the remarkable story of risk* (John Wiley & Sons 1996). There Francis Galton makes his snobbish and charming appearance as one player in a long line of mathematicians, philosophers, insurers, stockbrokers, and gamblers.